# regex statement for matching on last three charcaters with three digits

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have two servers that are wpoapp100 and wpodev02

I would like the syntax to match only on wpo and disregard app or the number. How would I do this?

Comment: Please provide an example of what you mean

Comment: A simple regular expression to match `wpo` in both strings would be. `^\w{3}`

Comment: A simple regex that matches anything beginning with **wpo** would be `/^wpo.*$/`

Comment: In `wpodev02`, there is no 3 digits at the last.

Comment: try this /^(?i)wpo.*$/

Answer (score 0):

use this for match only two words:

```
/^wpo(app100|dev02)$/
```

or use this to match any words stating with:

```
/^wpo[a-z0-9]*$/
```